# Moving data from Model to destination ViewController with segue

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and programming in general. I am building a quiz app. The app uses `TopicsViewController` to select a topic and segue to a `QuestionsViewController`. The questions for the various topics are stored as separate Swift Objects file. I would like to pick the Topic1 Question file when I press the topic1 button in `TopicsViewController` to segue into the `QuestionsViewController`. I would like to know how can I select the particular questions file QuestionBank1/QuestionBank2 when I select the particular topic upon segueing to the `QuestionsViewController`?

**Navigation Pane :**

[image: Navigation Pane]

**`Main.storyboard` :**

[image: Main.storyboard]

**`TopicsViewController`:**

```
import UIKit

class TopicsViewController: UIViewController, returnToTopicVCDelegate {

    func goToTopicVC() {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func goToQuestionsVCWhenPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToQuestionVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueToQuestionVC" {
            let quizVC = segue.destination as! QuizViewController
            quizVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

**`QuizViewController`:**

```swift
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

protocol returnToTopicVCDelegate{
    func goToTopicVC()
}

class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : returnToTopicVCDelegate?

    //outlet for the question label and image view
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionImageView: UIImageView!
    //outlet for the buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var optionAButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionCButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionDButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionEButton: UIButton!
    //outlets for the progress
    @IBOutlet weak var questionCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var selectedAnswer : Int = 0 // answer selected by the subject
    var questionNumber: Int = 0
    var score: Int = 0

    // functions executed after an answer is picked
    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == selectedAnswer {
            print("correct answer")
            sender.backgroundColor = .green
            score += 1
        } else {
            print("wrong")
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
            print("\(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].correctAnswer)")
            //the following two lines change the right answer button to green using the tag value of the button
            let correctAnswerButton = view.viewWithTag(selectedAnswer) as? UIButton
            correctAnswerButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }

    @IBAction func GoToNextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        questionNumber += 1
        nextQuestion()
    }

    // selects a new questions and updates the score

    func nextQuestion(){
        if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1 {
            questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].question
            questionImageView.image = UIImage(named: (allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionImage))
            optionAButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionA, for: UIControlState.normal)
            optionBButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionB, for: UIControlState.normal)
            optionCButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionC, for: UIControlState.normal)
            optionDButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionD, for: UIControlState.normal)
            optionEButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionE, for: UIControlState.normal)
            selectedAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].correctAnswer
            updateUI()
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Great!", message: "Do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) {(UIAlertAction) in
                self.restartQuiz()
            }
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func updateUI(){
        scoreLabel.text = "score: \(score)"
        questionCounter.text = "\(questionNumber + 1)/\(allQuestions.list.count)"
    }

    func restartQuiz(){
        score = 0
        questionNumber = 0
        nextQuestion()
    }


    @IBAction func goBackToTopicsVC(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.goToTopicVC()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you displaying your topics? normally you would use tableview, so you would use `indexPath.row` to determine which the user tapped

Comment: Topics are displayed as UIButton. I am able to go to the next view controller with Questions but I am not abe to fetch the questions swift file.

Comment: Cannot help you if you don't show your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps :

1- Add a segue from TopicsViewController to QuestionsViewController and give the segue "Identifier Name " from Attributes inspector.

2- Add a variable in QuestionsViewController for the topic lets name it "topicType".

3- Override the below function in TopicsViewController and send the name of the topic with the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Identifier Name" {
            if let destinationviewController = segue.destination as? QuestionsViewController , let buttonPressed = sender as? UIButton {
                destinationviewController.topicType = buttonPressed.currentTitle!  
            }
        }
}
```

4- For each button in TopicsViewController , get the button action and type the following function in it :

```
@IBAction func topicButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Identifier Name", sender: nil)

}
```

I hope this helps you .

Comment: Can you write the code and show the storyboard here so we can help you ??

Comment: Where and how do I put the code? I am new to programming/swift and to stack overflow. I have tried to press every link on my initial post and on the "add comment" section to insert my code. I am unable to do it. I have read other post with four spaces and all other "tricks". But I am not able to. help!!!!

Comment: I added the code and the images to show the storyboard.